# c++ simple increment program won't print correctly? what?

Tags: c++, cout

I've been learning c++ for the past few days and i started having this simple problem with my console not printing correctly, I had it working with much more complex programs the other day and now i cant even get this to work, help please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int variable = 1;
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
    cout << variable << endl;
    variable = increment(variable);
    cout << variable << endl;
    system("pause");
}

int increment(int a)
{
    a++;
    return a;
}
```

When i run the program the console prints

"hello world"

1

"press any button to continue"

Why doesn't the modified variable print?  I've tried this with a few setups and it seems
that after variable has printed once it won't print again, what's going on here?

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't even compile. `increment` isn't declared where you use it.

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile at this point.  When I fixed the syntax errors I get the output you expected.  Perhaps your syntax errors are preventing compilation and you are running an old version of the code?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. Are you sure you are not running an executable that built from older code?

Comment: Oh of course, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 5):

Your code shouldn't compile, you are probably running an older build. Either add a forward declaration of the increment function (`int increment(int);` before main) or put the definition of the increment function before the main method.

Comment: +1 for "You are probably running an older build"

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is: you are not declaring your (increment) function.

you are calling you function here:

```
variable = increment(variable);
```

and here, you are defining your function:

```
int increment(int a)
{
a++;
return a;
}
```

but before you call your function you need to declare it, try this:

```
int increment(int a); //just before (variable = increment(variable);)
```

Note: your code is not even compiling, but anyway if you comment the `system("pause");` line and include the declaration, it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

you must define :

```
int increment(int a);
```

before main

```
    using namespace std;
    int increment(int a);
    int main()
    {
        int variable = 1;
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
        cout << variable << endl;
        variable = increment(variable);
        cout << variable << endl;
        system("pause");
    }

    int increment(int a)
    {
        a++;
        return a;
    }
```